# PPA's are completely broken in 18.04.1, any possible solutions?

Tags: apt, 18.04, ppa

I tried adding a lot of PPA's in my newly installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 (LTS)

PPA for Adapta

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tista/adapta
```

PPA for Macbuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
```

and I waited for a long time and then I got this output

```
[sudo] password for sumeet: 
 This PPA is dedicated to Macbuntu transformation pack for Ubuntu.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/macbuntu
 Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.
```

I pressed "Enter" key and got this

```
Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
```

I've tried Rebooting and I've tried reinstalling the complete operating system. I've tried to add more than 10 PPA's

Comment: Do other commands such as `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` work normally? Any messages, errors, warnings?

Comment: @DKBose yes. other commands work fine. only PPA's can't be added.

Comment: You probably don't press `Enter` when you are asked. Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tista/adapta` command.

Comment: This means that the key server is blocked by your ISP.

Comment: Hello, @Pilot6 I updated my question with new findings. the problem still exists. and I did press Enter. I've been using Ubuntu for a couple years now

Comment: The system can't reach `keyserver.ubuntu.com` for some reason. maybe it's blocked in your country.

Comment: it's working with diffrent internet

Comment: I can open that website. on my connection

Comment: Can you use *any* PPA? I'm developing and maintaining [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), and its PPA works for me in all current versions and flavours of Ubuntu. It could help analyzing your problem, if you try the following commands: `sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu` and `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter` and `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi` and tell us the result.

Comment: You can try in: 1. Your current installed Ubuntu system; 2. A live drive with the same version, Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. - If it works in the live drive, but not in the installed system, the problem is in your installed system. If it does not work in any of the systems, I think the problem is with the internet connection, as indicated by @Pilot6.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Are you living in Russia? In actual state RosComNadzor can block any web-infrastructure for Russia or countries that have peering through Russia. Try to use some Proxy/VPN Provider for system to check if it is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that your system cannot access `keyserver.ubuntu.com` due some Network erros.
But you can manually add key for this repository(here is example for adapta).

1. Go to ppa repository on Launchpad: `https://launchpad.net/~tista/+archive/ubuntu/adapta`
2. Expand(click) at Technical details about this PPA
   [image: Thechnical details]
3. Click on the Signing key[image]
4. It will forward you to `keyserver.ubuntu.com` where you can manually download Public key for ppa repository. Click on link and you will get the the public key
   [image: Click]
5. Copy public key as text file on your system. Only parts from `BEGIN` and `AND` (including lines with begin and end)
   [image: Public key]
6. Import this key with ubuntu's Software and Updates in Authentication tab.
7. Issue `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install adapta-gtk-theme`

If it works than contact you ISP about this issue.
If it fails please provide your console output.

Comment: It worked, my ISP isn't helping. but thanks for this, at least I have a way now

Answer (score 1):

For me it was some issue with IPv6.

I went to Settings -> Network -> Wired -> IPv6 and changed "IPv6 Method" from "Disable" to "Automatic". After that I disabled and re-enabled the connection and tried again.

The command worked much faster and I didn't get time out error anymore.